# $scope value does not udate - Angularfire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I'm having a problem with my code. `$scope` value is not updating after `$createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. but if i do alert(`$scope.message`), I can see the alert. Where am i going wrong?

I'm using all the updated files from firebase and Angularfire.

My app.js

`
var spaapp = angular.module('spaapp', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);

```
spaapp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: 'spaController'
    }).
    when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'register.html',
        controller: 'spaController'
    }).
    when('/success', {
        templateUrl: 'success.html',
        controller: 'spaController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/Main'
    });
}]);
```

'
My Controller

```
   spaapp.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
   return $firebaseAuth();
  }
  ]);


spaapp.controller('spaController', ['$scope','$rootScope', 'Auth',function ($scope,$rootScope,Auth) {
   // $scope.authObj=firebaseAuth();
   //var auth = Auth;
    $scope.login = function () {

    }

    $scope.register = function () {


       var email = $scope.user.email;
      var password = $scope.user.password;

    Auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(regUser){
            $scope.message="Hi" + regUser.uid;
            console.log("Signed in as:" + regUser.uid );


        }).catch(
    function(error) {  
     var errorCode = error.code;
     var errorMessage = error.message;
     console.log(error.message);
     $scope.message = error.message;
     });
    };


}]);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh angular's `$scope` by calling `$apply()` on `$scope`

Example:

```
spaapp.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
   return $firebaseAuth();
  }
  ]);


spaapp.controller('spaController', ['$scope','$rootScope', 'Auth',function ($scope,$rootScope,Auth) {
   // $scope.authObj=firebaseAuth();
   //var auth = Auth;
    $scope.login = function () {

    }

    $scope.register = function () {


       var email = $scope.user.email;
      var password = $scope.user.password;

    Auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(regUser){
            $scope.message="Hi" + regUser.uid;
            console.log("Signed in as:" + regUser.uid );


        }).catch(
    function(error) {  
     var errorCode = error.code;
     var errorMessage = error.message;
     console.log(error.message);
     $scope.message = error.message;

     $scope.$apply() // HERE

     });
    };


}]);
```

More about angular's digest loop at:
http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: Thank you, I have used '$scope.$apply()' before but it's giving me an error Error: [$rootScope:inprog] .